# Given 49a + 49b = 6272, the average of a and b is 64. Why?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I found this math test very interesting. I would like to know how the answer is being calculate?

Comment: It is $\frac{a+b}2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $49a+49b=6272$, we can divide by $49$ to find that $a+b=128$. By definition the average of $a$ and $b$ is $\frac12(a+b)$, which is $\frac12\cdot128=64$. (Of course you can do this all at once by dividing by $2\cdot49$, but the logic is probably a little clearer the way I did it.)

Answer (score 2):

Divide both sides by $98{}{}{}{}$.

Comment: This doesn't answer Why.

Comment: In fact it does, @huahsin68...but it lets you do some work and some thinking *why*. +1

Comment: @DonAntonio +1 on your reply. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: $49a+49b=6272$ can be written as $49(a+b)=6272$ and the average of $a$ and $b$ can be written as $\large\frac{a+b}{2}$